# how to downgrade from iOS 6.1.3 to iOS 5.1.1 in iPhone 4?

Tags: ios, iphone

I have an iPhone 4. It has network lock from Switzerland. I want use Gevey SIM on this phone. Gevey SIM is more compatible for iOS 5.1.1.

how to downgrade from iOS 6.1.3 to iOS 5.1.1 in iPhone 4?

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible. Each time you *restore* an iOS device's OS, Apple **must** sign as valid the version you are trying to install, and once a version has been considered as *deprecated*, which usually is a couple of weeks after a new iOS version has been released, Apple stops providing a *valid certification* for it.